# RunTimeException for com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException:

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, runtime-error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

What does this mean? Never come across this error so please help out.

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: this error was appeared after you have updated to AS to 3.1 ?

Comment: No i just added firebaseui dependencies... after that i got this

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.0'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.1.0'
```

And this line of code:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
```

See [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android), which `FirebaseUI` version is compatible with which `Firebase/Play Services` version.